# How to implement a noise (sound) detection circuit

Tags: circuit-design

A biofeedback noise-control device simply informs of an over-threshold (human-produced) noise level in a room. It is composed of a small microphone, an element to filter out under-threshold input levels, and (typically) a lighting sign. What would be the best design for such a device in terms of cost, and ease of implementation?

Note: I've got little training in electricity when I was younger, and my first questions have not been well-received. Please, consider that beginners also deserve a place in this community before down-voting. Happy to edit following your suggestions.

Note: This question is motivated by the fact that while there exist commercial versions of these devices, their price is unrealistically high for some public schools and hospitals, like this popular solution: [SoundEar](https://www.noisemeters.com/product/soundear/) model. (It's not that I want to compete with these guys, just need to build one, and give others the information to implement a solution.)

Comment: You mention that your first questions were not well received, so really you need to understand why. If you've [read the help](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help), you should have a fair idea of what types of question are suitable. On the face of it, this question falls broadly into either *"please give me a design"* or *"please recommend a product"*, neither of which are on topic. Perhaps if you show a design that you have found, point out what you think are the shortcomings - how to reduce cost, improve performance, whatever, it will show that you have taken time to understand things.

Comment: For example, you ask *"What would be the best design for such a device?"*. In this there is no context, "best" means what? Cheapest, most reliable, lowest power, etc. You need a specification for a design to be made against. Also your last paragraph seems to focus on cost and implies that this may be something you want to commercialise. You need to explain more about *your* intention for such a device and maybe link to the devices whose *"price is unrealistically high"*. You see I'm trying to help, and not just downvoting?

Comment: To add to the comments in the answer that Transistor gave:  Good, clearly formulated questions from beginners are regularly answered here.  A well formulated question about something basic often leads to answers that help other people learn.  Your questions, however, don't fall into this class.  You show no sign of trying to understand, and your question is of no use to someone else who may be trying to learn.

Comment: To make your questions better, try to break the task down into parts and try to find circuits that you think could be used.  Explain what you are trying to do, explain why you think a particular circuit could be of use, then ask for help understanding the circuit. Find an example circuit for the next part the task, and repeat.  Once you have the needed circuitry for the task, assemble it into one circuit, again explain your task and ask if the circuit you have sketched will achieve your goals and how it can be improved.  Finally, build the device and see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Note that nearly all steps begin with you making an effort.  That is key to getting help here.  People like to help, but they get cranky when asked to do your job for you.

Comment: You've already broken the task into parts.  A few minutes on google would turn up examples on how to accomplish all parts of that task.

Comment: Other things that can make anyone cranky: Telling us how to spend our votes.

Comment: @RogerRowland it's not that I've just landed here, have spent quite some time interacting in other communities, but feel more limited in this field. It's hard to establish that line that put questions apart, but wanted to point out that I'm one of those rare cases where you need electronics, but don't have the time to start learning from the bottom. At this point, I just don't know how to attack my problem, but cannot either start with an electronics for dummies handbook. So, I come to this community asking for help.

Comment: I do think that the question is important, and other people might need a solution. Whether this is the place to find it or not, I don't know, but I think it is, and that's the reason because I asked to let it stay - if it wasn't, nobody would have answered (@pipe: don't want to tell others what to do, but to suggest a point of view that may differ with yours).

Comment: Now, regarding the target, yes, cost is important -as can be inferred-, but (given my expertise in the field, and probably also others') simplicity and ease of implementation does also matter (question updated). As for my intention, well, we want to install one in my daughter's classroom, that's it, but the school can't pay for a [SoundEar](https://www.noisemeters.com/product/soundear/) model (question updated), which might be the most popular one (don't know if there are others, but this wouldn't be so popular if there's another one which is way cheaper).

Comment: Finally, @JRE, thanks for your comments and point of view, but I just can't agree. Learning by example is done in other communities I have interacted with in this site, if your policy prefer to avoid it, it's OK, I just wanted to raise the discussion before my question was sent to the paper bin. (May be the meta community would had been a better place.) Plus, I googled it for quite some time, and couldn't even find a decent microphone for my circuit, all I've got was professional microphones for artists. Really, either you're in the field, or you're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just to respond to your point "*... consider that beginners also deserve a place in this community before down-voting.*". If the site is intended for electrical engineering having a load of beginners' questions really clutters it up and we find ourselves answering the same thing over and over again. To keep the standard of questions and answers high we need to discourage bad questions. So beginners don't necessarily "deserve" a place if that's the site policy.

Regarding the technical aspects of your question: you could investigate this in two parts: the microphone amplifier and the indicator circuit. Let's start with the indicator circuit.

The human ear has a logarithmic response to sound level. Each doubling of the level (+6 dB) is perceived as a linear increase in volume. A volume control built using a linear potentiometer will sound most un-linear in use with large changes in volume perceived in the inital rotation from zero and no perceived change towards the maximum. To solve this problem logarithmic or "log" pots are used. You just need to be aware of this in setting your threshold.

The [LM3915](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3915.pdf) dot/bar display is designed for use as an audio level meter. It has ten log spaced outputs capable of driving LEDs and the mode pin allows selection of bar or dot. Using this would give good visual feedback of the noise level and how close to the threshold the volume was getting.

[image]

*Figure 1. The basic LM3915 dot/bar display configuration has ten LEDs in 3 dB steps. Full scale display is obtained with a signal level of 1.2 V.*

If you build this circuit you can test it by feeding a variable voltage from a potentiometer into the SIG input. At 1.2 V all LEDs should be on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGkHvH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Switching the sign on and off.*

Figure 2 gives a possible solution to switching the sign on and off. Connect D3 to the switching point LED. When the LED is switched on Q1 will be turned on and the sign will light. The capacitor provides a short delay before turning off.

Finally you will need a microphone and a pre-amplifier to give 1.2 V peak output at the required volume. I will not give advice on that as there are plenty of circuits available on the web.

Comment: +1 for beginners don't necessarily "deserve" a place if that's the site policy.

Comment: It would be more accurate and fair to say that while beginners deserve a place, that place is an opportunity to follow the same expected process and procedures at as anyone else, but to do so at a beginner level of ability.  It is not a pass to *skip* necessary process.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a simpler device that implements the function of comparing the input with a given voltage threshold? We could adjust it to the reference noise level in the place where it will work, and that would make it.

Comment: Yes, it's a comparitor and there are ten of them in that chip (have a look at the datasheet). You can still use that chip and leave out all the LEDs but you'd lose the ability to gauge how close to tripping your are.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 555 and an electret microphone should get you what you want, as shown below.

R3 is used to adjust the 555's trigger point, and once the electret's output pulls U1-2 below the trigger point, the 555's output will go high for t = 1.1 R4 C2 seconds, where R4 is in ohms and C2 is in farads.

[image]

And here's the LTspice circuit list so you can play with the circuit if you want to:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 2680 692
WIRE -2864 -6752 -3120 -6752
WIRE -2704 -6752 -2864 -6752
WIRE -2592 -6752 -2704 -6752
WIRE -2272 -6752 -2592 -6752
WIRE -2864 -6688 -2864 -6752
WIRE -2704 -6688 -2704 -6752
WIRE -2976 -6528 -3008 -6528
WIRE -2960 -6528 -2976 -6528
WIRE -2864 -6528 -2864 -6608
WIRE -2864 -6528 -2896 -6528
WIRE -2848 -6528 -2864 -6528
WIRE -2544 -6528 -2848 -6528
WIRE -2272 -6528 -2272 -6752
WIRE -2272 -6528 -2320 -6528
WIRE -2704 -6464 -2704 -6608
WIRE -2544 -6464 -2704 -6464
WIRE -2192 -6464 -2320 -6464
WIRE -2272 -6432 -2272 -6528
WIRE -2704 -6400 -2704 -6464
WIRE -2544 -6400 -2704 -6400
WIRE -3120 -6368 -3120 -6752
WIRE -3008 -6368 -3008 -6528
WIRE -2848 -6368 -2848 -6528
WIRE -2704 -6352 -2704 -6400
WIRE -2592 -6336 -2592 -6752
WIRE -2544 -6336 -2592 -6336
WIRE -2272 -6336 -2272 -6368
WIRE -2272 -6336 -2320 -6336
WIRE -3120 -6224 -3120 -6288
WIRE -3008 -6224 -3008 -6288
WIRE -3008 -6224 -3120 -6224
WIRE -2848 -6224 -2848 -6288
WIRE -2848 -6224 -3008 -6224
WIRE -2704 -6224 -2704 -6288
WIRE -2704 -6224 -2848 -6224
WIRE -2272 -6224 -2272 -6336
WIRE -2272 -6224 -2704 -6224
WIRE -3120 -6160 -3120 -6224
FLAG -3120 -6160 0
FLAG -2192 -6464 OUT
FLAG -2976 -6528 MIC
SYMBOL AI555 -2432 -6432 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL cap -2288 -6432 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMBOL res -2720 -6704 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1meg
SYMBOL cap -2720 -6352 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 4.7µ
SYMBOL res -2880 -6704 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1meg
SYMBOL res -2864 -6384 R0
WINDOW 0 -43 30 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -59 62 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 510K
SYMBOL cap -2896 -6544 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL voltage -3008 -6384 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value SINE(6 .1 1000 1 0 0 10)
SYMBOL Misc\\battery -3120 -6384 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 12
TEXT -3106 -6190 Left 2 !.tran 10
TEXT -2560 -6248 Left 2 ;EM FIELDS  25 SEP 2016
```